# How do you delete the header in a dataframe?

Tags: r, header, dataframe

I want to delete the header from a dataframe that I have. I read in the data from a csv file then I transposed it, but it created a new header that is the name of the file and the row that the data is from in the file.

Here's an example for a dataframe df:

```
     a.csv.1   a.csv.2   a.csv.3   ...
  x        5         6         1   ...
  y        2         3         2   ...
```

I want to delete the a.csv.n row, but when I try `df <- df[-1,]` it deletes row x and not the top.

Comment: The question remains why you want to delete that header if you want to work on the data.frame.

Comment: @Metrics I think, itsn't the issue

Answer (score 12):

If you really, really, really don't like column names, you may convert your data frame to a matrix (keeping possible coercion of variables of different `class` in mind), and then remove the `dimnames`.

```
dd <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5, x2 = 11:15)
mm1 <- as.matrix(dd)
mm2 <- matrix(mm1, ncol = ncol(dd), dimnames = NULL)
```

I add my previous comment here as well:
`?data.frame`: "The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results.".

Answer (score 11):

Set names to NULL

```
names(df) <- NULL
```

You can also use the `header` option in `read.csv`

Comment: That will give `NA` in colnames.

Comment: your answer gave me an excelent ideia for something similar. I had a data.frame with names and i wanted to write  in .txt without the names :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `names(df)` to change the names of header or col names. If newnames is a list of names as `newname<-list("col1","col2","col3")`, then `names(df)<-newname` will give you a data with col names as col1 col2 col3.

As @ Henrik said, the col names should be non-empty. Setting the `names(df)<-NULL`will give NA in col names.

If your data is csv file and if you use header=TRUE to read the data in R then the data will have same colnames as csv file, but if you set the header=FALSE, R will assign the colnames as V1,V2,...and your colnames in the original csv file appear as a first row.

```
anydata.csv  
      a b c  d
    1 1 2 3 13
    2 2 3 1 21

read.csv("anydata.csv",header=TRUE)
      a b c  d
    1 1 2 3 13
    2 2 3 1 21

read.csv("anydata.csv",header=FALSE)

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  b  c  d
2  1  2  3 13
3  2  3  1 21
```

Comment: how do I change it to nothing?

Comment: `?data.frame`: "The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have unsupported results.".

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
setNames(dat, rep(" ", length(dat)))
```

where `dat` is the name of the data frame. Then all columns will have the name `" "` and hence will be 'invisible'.

Comment: To be precise, you want `dat <- setNames(dat, *)`. Leaving off the assignment could give the impression that `setNames` modifies an object in place, like setters do other languages. And if you're making an explicit assignment, you might as well just use `names(dat) <- *`.

Answer (score 3):

It comes with some years of delay but you can simply use a vector renaming de columns:

```
## if you want to delete all column names:
colnames(df)[] <- ""

## if you want to delete let's say column 1:
colnames(df)[1] <- ""

## if you want to delete 1 to 3 and 7:
colnames(df)[c(1:3,7)] <- ""
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned not having column names just isn't something that is going to happen with a data frame, but I'm kind of guessing that you don't care so much if they are there you just don't want to see them when you print your data frame? If so, you can write a new print function to get around that, like so:

```
> dat <- data.frame(var1=c("A","B","C"),var2=rnorm(3),var3=rnorm(3))
> print(dat)
  var1       var2       var3
1    A  1.2771777 -0.5726623
2    B -1.5000047  1.3249348
3    C  0.1989117 -1.4016253
> ncol.print <- function(dat) print(matrix(as.matrix(dat),ncol=ncol(dat),dimnames=NULL),quote=F)
> ncol.print(dat)
     [,1] [,2]       [,3]      
[1,] A     1.2771777 -0.5726623
[2,] B    -1.5000047  1.3249348
[3,] C     0.1989117 -1.4016253
```

Your other option it set your variable names to unique amounts of whitespace, for example:

```
> names(dat) <- c(" ", "  ", "   ")
> dat

1 A  1.2771777 -0.5726623
2 B -1.5000047  1.3249348
3 C  0.1989117 -1.4016253
```

You can also write a function do this:

```
> blank.names <- function(dat){
+   for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){
+     names(dat)[i] <- paste(rep(" ",i),collapse="")
+   }
+   return(dat) 
+ }
> dat <- data.frame(var1=c("A","B","C"),var2=rnorm(3),var3=rnorm(3))
> dat
  var1        var2       var3
1    A -1.01230289  1.2740237
2    B -0.13855777  0.4689117
3    C -0.09703034 -0.4321877
> blank.names(dat)

1 A -1.01230289  1.2740237
2 B -0.13855777  0.4689117
3 C -0.09703034 -0.4321877
```

But generally I don't think any of this should be done.

Comment: After seeing Sven's answer it turns out I was wrong about the whitespace needing to be unique for the second approach, not sure why `names(dat) <- " "` doesn't work and `names(dat) <- c(" ", " ", " ")` does though...

Answer (score 0):

A function that I use in one of my R scripts:

```
read_matrix <- function (csvfile) {
    a <- read.csv(csvfile, header=FALSE)
    matrix(as.matrix(a), ncol=ncol(a), dimnames=NULL)
}
```

How to call this:

```
iops_even <-  read_matrix('even_iops_Jan15.csv')
iops_odd  <-  read_matrix('odd_iops_Jan15.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```py
print(df.to_string(header=False))
```

if you want to remove the line indexes as well, you can do:

```py
print(df.to_string(index=False,header=False))
```