# How to print certain rows of a dataframe with a condition

Tags: r, indexing, printing

From the data.frame below, I want to use the print() function to simply print out the row information (date and temp) of any rows that have a "red" warnings variable. I have tried with indexing but am having no luck! Tia

```
              date  temp warnings
            <dttm> <dbl>    <chr>
 1 2017-04-16 10:00:00  26.3    black
 2 2017-04-17 10:00:00  25.7    black
 3 2017-04-18 10:00:00  25.4    black
 4 2017-04-19 10:00:00  25.6    black
 5 2017-04-20 10:00:00  25.9    black
 6 2017-04-21 10:00:00  26.1    black
 7 2017-04-22 10:00:00  27.8    red
 8 2017-04-23 10:00:00  26.3    black
 9 2017-04-24 10:00:00  26.1    black
10 2017-04-25 10:00:00  26.6    black
```

Thanks everyone! I have had a play around with your suggestions and managed to Print though is there anyway to neaten this up and not print the column titles?

```
df[df$warnings == 'red', c('date', 'temp')]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
                 date  temp
               <dttm> <dbl>
1 2017-05-27 10:00:00  27.8
2 2017-05-29 10:00:00  27.7
```

Comment: Indexing should work ... can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: I'm very new to r so you will have to excuse my lack of understanding... which data would you like an example of? Is the sample of data.frame visible that I attached to the Question? Otherwise I have a huge data.frame with more variables as well but really just need to print when the temp is greater then 27 and what the corresponding time is?

Comment: Just the sample that you pasted.  Can you dput() it here?

Comment: df[df$warnings == 'red', c('date', 'temp')] or df[df$warnings == 'red', 1:2] should do it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Please see the edited post for one last question :)

Comment: done! again! phew!

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks for all your time helping with this project today @Ajay Ohri . Im finally done :)

Answer (score 2):

I use for tasks like this the package 'dplyr'.

```
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
filter(my_df, warnings =='red')
```

where my_df is the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library("readr")
> red2=read_csv("red.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  date = col_character(),
  temp = col_double(),
  warning = col_character()
)
> red2
# A tibble: 10 x 3
              date  temp warning
             <chr> <dbl>   <chr>
 1 4/16/2017 10:00  26.3   black
 2 4/17/2017 10:00  25.7   black
 3 4/18/2017 10:00  25.4   black
 4 4/19/2017 10:00  25.6   black
 5 4/20/2017 10:00  25.9   black
 6 4/21/2017 10:00  26.1   black
 7 4/22/2017 10:00  27.8     red
 8 4/23/2017 10:00  26.3   black
 9 4/24/2017 10:00  26.1   black
10 4/25/2017 10:00  26.6   black
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> red2$date=mdy_hm(red2$date)
> red2
# A tibble: 10 x 3
                  date  temp warning
                <dttm> <dbl>   <chr>
 1 2017-04-16 10:00:00  26.3   black
 2 2017-04-17 10:00:00  25.7   black
 3 2017-04-18 10:00:00  25.4   black
 4 2017-04-19 10:00:00  25.6   black
 5 2017-04-20 10:00:00  25.9   black
 6 2017-04-21 10:00:00  26.1   black
 7 2017-04-22 10:00:00  27.8     red
 8 2017-04-23 10:00:00  26.3   black
 9 2017-04-24 10:00:00  26.1   black
10 2017-04-25 10:00:00  26.6   black
```

Choose only those rows that have warning red, choose only two columns by their column number

```
>     red2[red2$warning=="red",1:2]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
                 date  temp
               <dttm> <dbl>
1 2017-04-22 10:00:00  27.8
```

Now to tackle the problem of large data, I simulate the data to be bigger

```
> red3=red2[rep(seq_len(nrow(red2)), each=2000000),]
> str(red3)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       20000000 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ date   : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-16 10:00:00" "2017-04-16 10:00:00" ...
 $ temp   : num  26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 26.3 ...
 $ warning: chr  "black" "black" "black" "black" ...
> system.time(red3[red3$warning=="red",1:2])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.06    0.24
```

Now for printing out data without the column headers we use matrix with dimnames =NULL from [How do you delete the header in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175602/how-do-you-delete-the-header-in-a-dataframe)

```
 > out=red2[red2$warning=="red",1:2]> out.print <- function(dat) print(matrix(as.matrix(out),ncol=ncol(out),dimnames=NULL),quote=F)
> out.print(out)
     [,1]                [,2]
[1,] 2017-04-22 10:00:00 27.8
```

Comment: It isn't clear why the OPs indexing didn't work; nor what the following <dttm> <dbl>    <chr> means>.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: you get that when you import by readr in Rstudio- seems like variable types

Comment: you get that when you import by readr in Rstudio- seems like variable types , <dbl> is double or numeric, <chr> is charachter, <dttm> is date.